# Distribution of 4 distinct objects among 10 people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose I want to distribute $4$ different prizes among $10$ students. In how many ways can I do so?
One method goes like this: for each prize, I have $10$ choices. Hence, by the *Fundamental Principle of Counting*, the answer comes out to be $10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10= {10^4}$.

I see that this solution is quite efficient and pleasing but I want to explore the other possible consistent ways of solving the problem.

EDIT: The $4$ prizes can go independently to any of the $10$ students, i.e. one has to count *all* the possible distributions of the prizes, among those $10$ students.

One method that I tried is to consider the cases of distribution of the prizes, which are: all $4$ go to a single student$;$ $3$ go to one student and $1$ goes to another$;$ $2$ prizes go to a student and the rest $2$ prizes go to another student. Now, I tried to find the number of ways in which each case is possible. For e.g. if all $4$ go to a single student of the $10$ students, it possible in only $10$ ways. Thus, after finding the total number of ways in which all the mentioned $3$ cases can occur, we can just add the numbers to get the required answer. I may be wrong with such a method and if so, I'd appreciate if you point it out for me and also discuss an alternative solution.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. If $4$ prizes can independently go to any of the $10$ students then this is the way (which means a student could even get all the $4$ prizes and others could be left out). So it depends on what conditions you have.

Comment: @MathLover apologies for the inconvenience you had in comprehending the problem.... Yes, the prizes can independently go to any of the $10$ students... Have edited the question for avoiding any further future ambiguities...

Comment: Your alternative method will work.  However, there are five cases since \begin{align*} 4 & = 4\\ & = 3 + 1\\ & = 2 + 2\\ & = 2 + 1 + 1\\ & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \end{align*}  If you count those distributions correctly, they will add to $10^4$.